nodejs Multer middleware req.file undefined but req.body hail
I want to upload images with Multer and when I test it with postmanden it works fine but when I send a request with axios the req.file is undefined but I get the data I want in req.body and I get error 400 in frontend.
localhost = myl local ıp
multer.ts
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import multer from "multer";

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "uploads/",
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
    cb(null, uniqueSuffix);
  },
});

const uploads = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
    files: 1,
    fieldSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
  },
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "image/png") {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(new Error("File type not supported!"));
    }
  },
});

interface RequestWithUser extends Request {
  user?: {
    id: number;
    email: string;
  };
}

export function uploadImage(
  req: RequestWithUser,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) {
  uploads.single("image")(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      console.error("MulterError =>", err.message);
      return res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
    }
    if (err) {
      console.error("MulterError =>", err.message);
      return res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
    }
    if (!req.file) {
      console.error("Please upload an image");
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Please upload an image" });
    }

    console.log("req.body MWW =>", req.body);

    console.log("req.file MWW =>", req.file);

    next();
  });
}

router.post(
  "/create-image",
  authorize,
  uploadImage,
  createImageController.createImage
);

Example axios request
const handleGenerateImage = async (prompt: string, image: string) => {
    const formData = new FormData();

     for (const [key, value] of Object.entries({ prompt, image })) {
       formData.append(key, value as string | Blob);
     }

     console.log("formData", formData);


    try {
      const result = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/create-image",
        formData,
        {
          responseType: "json",
          headers: {
            Accept: "multipart/form-data",
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
          },
        }
      );
      console.log("result", result);
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error);
      return;
    }
  };

Error
LOG  error [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400]**
Form data log
**
LOG  formData {"_parts": [["prompt", "Superman"], ["image", "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FstickerAI-4f69cda2-177b-4e6a-9b97-2784a47b4c88/ImagePicker/2fcasdf1-30f5-4149-89a1-0304b7b3acfc.jpeg"]]}
I tried taking the data from req.body and assigning it to req.file,
I tried with req.files and tried to use it as an array,
I tried removing content-typpe,
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); tried it as true false,
and etc
fetch result =>
{
   "_bodyBlob":{
      "_data":{
         "__collector":[
            "Object"
         ],
         "blobId":"e40a7871-51f9-4678-a309-e467bcdbab3e",
         "offset":0,
         "size":36
      }
   },
   "_bodyInit":{
      "_data":{
         "__collector":[
            "Object"
         ],
         "blobId":"e40a7871-51f9-4678-a309-e467bcdbab3e",
         "offset":0,
         "size":36
      }
   },
   "bodyUsed":false,
   "headers":{
      "map":{
         "access-control-allow-origin":"*",
         "connection":"keep-alive",
         "content-length":"36",
         "content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8",
         "date":"Mon, 29 Apr 2024 08:56:49 GMT",
         "etag":"W/\"24-RuEUrN0QtPlwvGJylleayGNbKK0\"",
         "keep-alive":"timeout=5",
         "x-powered-by":"Express"
      }
   },
   "ok":false,
   "status":400,
   "statusText":"",
   "type":"default",
   "url":"http://localhost:5000/api/create-image"
}

Solution
I sent not only image uri but all image values and the problem was solved for example
 LOG image { “name”: “IMG_20240427_211307.jpg”, “type”: “image/jpeg”, “uri”: “file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FstickerAI-4f69cda2-177b-4e6a-9b97-2784a47b4c88/ImagePicker/b1840a7f-8669-4b54-84e5-e4f03b306321.jpeg”}


Try switching value as string | Blob to value as Blob | string

LOG error [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400] I keep getting this error

try converting image to Blob, and then append to form data, and then submit request without content type header

ı try image to blob, response axios network error @traynor :(

try hardcoding some blob and then appending it, just to narrow the problem. I'd say the problem is with appending the file on frontend, and the file is not parsed or corrupted... if you're using some library, you should mention that and include the code. also, on backend, check which error block throws, does multer give some error, or the file is undefined etc.

for the front end I only use the reac local image picker to get the images.
on the backend mutler doesn't give an error the data just doesn't reach req.file but the image url that should go to req.file appears in req.body for example req.body = prompt = “superman”, image=“”file:///data/user/0/....jpeg“”

Also postmanden works smoothly when I test it

react works smoothly in website app with axios, but not in react native expo app @traynor

try searching for some solutions with the image picker then, for example: React Native : convert local image to url
